# ¿Cómo genero los datos de una impresión desde función conpile de angular manejando ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

Buenas tardes.

Quisiera saber si alguien me puede colaborar con la solución al siguiente problema:

Deseo imprimir un `html` dinámico estoy trabajando con [angular](/questions/tagged/angular). Al generar la impresión no me quiere reconocer los datos que están en `ng-repeat`.

Estoy utilizando la función compile de angular y el siguiente es el código que estoy implementando:

```
<tr ng-repeat="elemento in arreglo_seleccion">
    <td>{{elemento['@IUnAlterno']}}</td>
    <td style="text-align:right;">{{parseFloat(elemento['@valor'])|currency}}</td>
    <td>{{elemento['@areaPrivada']}}</td>
    <td ng-if="es_habitacional(elemento)">{{elemento['@areaConstruida']}}</td>
    <td ng-if="es_habitacional(elemento)">{{elemento['@areaLote']}}</td>
    <td ng-if="es_habitacional(elemento)">{{elemento['@areaTecnica']}}</td>
    <td ng-if="es_habitacional(elemento)">{{elemento['@areaTerraza']}}</td>
    <td ng-if="es_habitacional(elemento)">{{elemento['@areaBalcon']}}</td>
    <td ng-if="es_habitacional(elemento)">{{elemento['@areaPatio']}}</td>
    <td ng-if="!es_habitacional(elemento)" colspan="6">DESCRIPCION</td>
</tr>
```

y esta es la función de compile en el js:

```
mi_html = $compile(angular.element('#cuerpocorreo'))($scope);
           $timeout(function(){
               $scope.$digest();
           });
           print_win = new BrowserWindow();
           print_win.loadURL("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + 
           encodeURI(mi_html[0].innerHTML));


       print_win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function() {
            print_win.webContents.print(); 
        });
       print_win.on('closed', function() {
            print_win = null;
        });
```

Los datos que están encerrados en círculo rojo, son los datos que necesito me aparezcan y están generándose por medio de un `ng-repeat`, pero al momento de imprimir no me los está tomando.

Comment: me gustaría saber la razón por la que elegiste utilizar la directiva ng-if, si lo que deseas es mostrar/ocultar un elemento, seria recomendable utilizar un ng-show https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow intenta con esto, suerte!

Comment: validaste que el $scope tenga items en el array que requiere el ng-repeat ?

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la llamada a `$scope.$digest();` debería estar fuera el `$timeout`. Algo así te podría funcionar:

```
   mi_html = $compile(angular.element('#cuerpocorreo'))($scope);
       //$timeout(function(){
           $scope.$digest();
       //});
       print_win = new BrowserWindow();
       print_win.loadURL("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + 
       encodeURI(mi_html[0].innerHTML));


   print_win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function() {
        print_win.webContents.print(); 
    });
   print_win.on('closed', function() {
        print_win = null;
    });
```

Échale un ojo a este [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DUM7t/22/)

Comment: Hola @andrea si esta o cualquier otra respuesta ha resuelto su problema, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) clicando la marca de check (en forma de V debajo de la puntuación de la respuesta). Esto indica a la comunidad que has encontrado una solución y de paso os dará reputación a ambos (a tí y quien ha respondido). Por supuesto, no tienes ninguna obligación de hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Quizas lo que te esta sucediendo es lo que comenta aquí

[HTML Compiler](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler)

analiza el titulo: `The difference between Compile and Link`

Detalle como la compilación procesa el `ng-repeat` procesando los nodos del html, quizas viene por este lado el problema.

Buscando por este camino encontre

[ngRepeat in compiled by $compile does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24638351/ngrepeat-in-compiled-by-compile-does-not-work)

creo que podria ayudar a resolver el problema

Comment: Este es exactamente el problema que le está ocurriendo. Quizás debas ampliar un poco mas la respuesta y postear un snipet de código con la solución correcta.